# What does this "c" symbol mean?

Tags: complex-numbers

What does this mean?

[image]

For context, the problem is $z^2+8=0$. I've come to the conclusion that $z=2i\sqrt2$, but I don't know what that $c$ thing is.

Comment: The C written that way is quite odd. Generally the set of complex numbers is represented by $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: When referring to special sets which occur frequently throughout literature or your studies, they often receive special symbols and iconography and may be embellished or use special font to emphasize their importance.  The letters used are often standardized but the font used might not be, particularly as it comes to handwriting or typing outside of $\LaTeX$.  You will generally see the letter R used for the real numbers ($R,\Bbb R, \mathcal{R},\textbf{R},\dots$) and Q for rational numbers, C for complex numbers, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that $\cal C$ in this context is the field Of complex numbers.

Solving an equation over a field $\mathbb F$ means finding all solutions for the equation in $\mathbb F$.

For example, your equation $x^2 + 8 = 0$ has no solution over $\mathbb R$ but it has 2 solutions over $\mathbb C$ (or $\cal C$) using the notation in your question.

Comment: so the answer is what I have?

Comment: Yes @CoolDoodShooz1 the "solve the equation over ___" is just telling you what kind of solutions they are asking for

Comment: @CoolDoodShooz1 the answer should be $z=\pm 2i \sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

The complex numbers $ \ \ \ \ \ \\ \ $

Comment: "The set of complex numbers" is a good word rather than just complex numbers